# rqt with topic monitor

Tags: ros, topic, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm new to the ROS community, and is currently working on drone related projects. Somebody hinted me to check the syntax and available messages to be published/subscribed with the use of rqt with topic monitor.

What does that mean? Will appreciate if someone could point me to the right material too!

Please advice

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249747/rqt-with-topic-monitor/) by [karkin96](https://answers.ros.org/users/28766/karkin96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rqt](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt) is a framework for building ROS visualization tools.

You may wnat to bring up the base rqt UI and play with [available plugins](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Plugins) to get a sense for what they can do.

You may also want to go through the [ROS Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials), one of the last and most-overlooked tutorials is [Navigating the Wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/NavigatingTheWiki), but it's also one of the best places for learning about specific ROS tools and packages.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1